# javascript "execute-all" method for all instances of an object

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say I have the following:

```
function FooBar (s) {
  this.s = s;
  this.logS = function () { console.log(this.s)}
}
var Foo = new FooBar('foo');
var Bar = new FooBar('bar');
```

My goal is to call `.logS()` for every instance of `FooBar`.  I can do this by calling them individually:

```
Foo.logS();
Bar.logS();
```

But let's say I do not know the names of all the objects of type FooBar - is there a method to execute all of them? For example, in principle I want to have this line of code: `FooBar.logS()` equate to calling `Foo.logS()` and `Bar.logS()`.

Well that obviously doesn't work, but I'm looking for something like that in principle. Failing that, is there a way to get a list of names of all objects that are instanceof FooBar?

For example, I can do this:

```
for (var o in window) { 
  if (window[o] instanceof FooBar) {
    window[o].logS();
  }
}
```

But that only works for objects directly under `window`.  If I were to say do this...

```
var bazs = [new FooBar('baz')];
```

...the loop wouldn't work. I suppose I could make a function to recursively walk through `window` but I think at best that would be slow but may not even find all of them (maybe?)

**TL;DR**

The goal is to find every `object` where `(object instanceof FooBar)` regardless of where `object` nested within `window`

Possible?

**Edit: Clarification**

I apologize, it seems I was not being clear enough. The suggested methods for keeping track of instances as they are created are great (array, subscription), but it's not what I need.

More detailed scenario. There is a 3rd party script that is used multiple times throughout a webpage. I get to insert my own code at the bottom of the page.  So, I do not get to alter FooBar to keep track of things from the get-go, before any instances of it are created. So my code needs to find all instances of FooBar that *already exist* when my code is executed.

Comment: Not sure what your exact scenario is, but would something like pub/sub suit you better ?

Comment: @Dimitar: That's a good idea. Amended my answer, but will remove it if you choose to provide a more extensive one.

Comment: @FelixKling Nope it's perfect, one of the upvotes is from me :)

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov good ideas but i don't think it's what i need; please see my edit

Comment: Well, in that case, while you can certainly iterate over all *global variables* and check whether any of those is an instance of `FooBar`, you won't find instances that are defined in a different scope.

Comment: No.  Unless you specifically keep track of all instances of a particular type of object, there is no way in javascript to just find them all and execute a method on them.  Not possible without prior planning to keep track of them all or knowing how/where they are stored.  Internal to the implementation of the language, there's probably a proprietary, implementation-specific way, but not in the standard language features.

Answer (score 2):

You could make so that creating a new instance of `FooBar` adds that instance to an array. E.g.:

```
function FooBar() {
    FooBar.instances.push(this);
    // ...
}
FooBar.instances = [];

FooBar.logS = function() {
    FooBat.instances.forEach(function(instance) {
        instance.logS();
    });
};
```

---

Alternatively you could implement an event handling or publish/subscriber system where each instance of `FooBar` listens to a specific event, which you then simply trigger. E.g.

```
function FooBar() {
    // ...
    Arbiter.subscribe('logS', this.logS.bind(this));
}

Arbiter.inform('logS');
```

If you don't want to implement something like this on your own, there are existing libraries out there, e.g. https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS

Comment: This is great, but I don't think this is what I need; please see edit in my question